# jni native method problems

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

hi everyone I'm working on some java code which call functions from a c++ dll. But some functions from the dll can be called correctly, while others can not. 
  I first write a java class wrap all the functions from the dll, then using javah generate the corresponding jni header file. At last I write c++ code include the generated jni header file. The c++ file was written in Visual Studio and the java code was written in Eclipse.

Below is my code,I have remove some irrelevant code.

Java:

```
public class VideoDetecion {
    static {

        System.load("dll_video_detect.dll");
        System.load("vd_jni_impl.dll");
    }

    public static native int getFrame(String videoName, int second,String frameName);
    public static native int getFrame1(String videoName);
    public static native int getFrame2(String videoName, int second);
}
```

c++

```
using cv::VideoCapture;
using cv::Mat;
using std::string;
using std::bind;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

using namespace std::placeholders;


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame1
(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jstring videoName)
{
    //String videoName = "D:\\videos\\detect1\\0.mp4";
    shared_ptr<const char> vn(env->GetStringUTFChars(videoName, NULL), bind(&JNIEnv::ReleaseStringUTFChars, env, videoName, _1));

    int second = 10;
    string frameName = "D:\\videos\\detect1\\0-10.jpg";

    vd::getVideoFrame(string(vn.get()), second, frameName);
    return 0;
}

/*
* Class:     videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion
* Method:    getFrame2
* Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;I)I
*/
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame2
(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jstring videoName, jint second)
{
    shared_ptr<const char> vn(env->GetStringUTFChars(videoName, NULL), bind(&JNIEnv::ReleaseStringUTFChars, env, videoName, _1));


    string frameName = "D:\\videos\\detect1\\0-10.jpg";

    vd::getVideoFrame(string(vn.get()), second, frameName);
    return 0;
}



JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame
(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring videoName, jint second, jstring frameName)
{
    shared_ptr<const char> vn(env->GetStringUTFChars(videoName, NULL), bind(&JNIEnv::ReleaseStringUTFChars,env, videoName,_1));
    shared_ptr<const char> fn(env->GetStringUTFChars(frameName, NULL), bind(&JNIEnv::ReleaseStringUTFChars,env,frameName,_1));


    if (videoName == NULL || frameName==NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    vd::getVideoFrame(string(vn.get()), second, string(fn.get()));

    return 0;
}
```

The error message from eclipse was:
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: videoDetectionJNI.VideoDetecion.getFrame(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;)I
    at videoDetectionJNI.VideoDetecion.getFrame(Native Method)
    at videoDetectionJNI.Test.main(Test.java:48)

what makes me miserable is that the method getFrame1 and getFrame2 works correctly, but the real method getFrame that I want does not.

Furthermore, when I use Visual Studio to attach to the process java.exe to debug the program, the program can stop on breakpoint in function of getFrame1 and getFrame2 in cpp file, but would not stop on breakpoint in function of getFrame.

Can somoeone help me? It really make me confused.

ps. I'am new to java.

Comment: What does `dumpbin /exports vd_jni_impl.dll` show? i.e. are the symbols that you think exported actually exported? And secondly have you rerun `javah` because the last function's signature doesn't match what comes from running it against the .java file (even with it placed into a `videoDetectionJNI` package).

Comment: 5    4 00001221 Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame0 = @ILT+
540(Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame0)
          6    5 00001226 Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame1 = @ILT+
545(Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame1)
          7    6 00001230 Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame2 = @ILT+
555(Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame2)

Comment: three function are all exported. I have rerun the javah(through Eclipse) and the header file are newest

Comment: OMG. The functions that can not be called in java were renamed by c++. But the header file generated by javah declared all the functions in a extern "c" macro. Besides, all functions have same form except their name and parameters.

Comment: Eh the function as exported is `getFrame0`, but the function as looked for in JNI is `getFrame`. Additionally, when you compile code in C++ it gets name mangled so that it can be referred to by function signature (e.g. overloaded methods). If you mis-state the type of one of the parameters e.g. using `jobject` instead of `jclass` for the second parameter of the method, the definition that's in the `.h` file, which tells the compiler **not** to mangle the functions (the `extern "C" {` wrapped around the declaration) does not match so the method ends up mangled, and thus cannot be found

Comment: The `.h` file I mention is the one produced by `javah` and *must* be `#include`'d into the `.cpp` file so that name mangling gets disabled. Because the definition in the `.cpp` file has `jobject` as the second parameter, then it implies that the method as defined in the `.java` file is **not** static, but is, in fact, an instance method

Comment: The definition of functions in javah generated header file is like this:JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jint, jstring);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame0
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame1
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame2
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jint);   getFrame was name mangled but the other this was not! It is so weird.

Comment: the declaration of the function is generated by javah so jclass is used. In the cpp file, I just copy the declaration also jclass not jobject

Comment: The source you posted for `Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame` indicates that the second parameter is `jobject`, which doesn't match the `.h`. This *will* cause the function not to get exported.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have changed the property of method and generate the  header file several times and get confused.

Comment: So working once you changed the method signature for `Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame`? If that's the case then I'll add a detailed answer

Comment: Yes. The method getFrame in the java class used to be non-static, so the generated signature is of ( jobject ). Later, I change the method getFrame to static method, so the generated signature is of ( jclass).  But the implementation of the method is still of (jobject) which I don't change as the signature of method has changed. So here   is problem, there is a funcion declared in the javah generated .h , but I didn't implement it ( although I have a function named getFrame , but it's not the one declared in the .h file), the compiler doesn't give a warning or error message.

Comment: C++ compilers are good at finding function definitions without function declarations. If you automatically regenerate your header files whenever your .class files change, this works to your advantage: Changing the Java signature will likely break the C++ build.

Comment: I have changed the java signature at once as the java class change. The declaration in the header file .h does not match the implementation but the compiler doesn't give a error message. I think that is because this a dll project, the JINEXPORT　defined as __declspec(export).

Answer (score 3):

Your Java signature

```
public static native int getFrame(String videoName, int second,String frameName);
```

does not match your c++ implementation signature.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_videoDetectionJNI_VideoDetecion_getFrame
(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring videoName, jint second, jstring frameName)
```

Either change your Java signature to be non-static, or change the second parameter of your c++ implementation signature to jclass from jobject.